# Longest path between two points in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, google-polyline

Apparently to draw a line (Polyline) between two locations in google maps, the api draws the line with the shortest path. For example: a line between NY and London would by default go through the Atlantic. The code goes something like this:

```
var path = [];
path.push(marker1.getPosition());
path.push(marker2.getPosition());

var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    map: map,
    geodesic: true
});
```

Now what I actually need is to draw the opposite line which starts from NY but goes through the Pacific and Asia then to London.

Is this even something I can achieve?

Comment: It will be not longest path. You should draw poly line by yourself using more then 2 points.

Comment: That would be too difficult. The path is not fixed but dynamic.

Comment: compute a point in the center of the path you want it to take.

Comment: I don't know if I can do that with "geodesic=true", I need it to be one line(curve).

Comment: You would need to calculate the center of the shortest path, then calculate it's coordinates in the opposite side of the earth (inverting the sign, perhaps). You can't do it on one stroke. Google Maps API will automatically switch to the shortest path once you pass half an earth. See it for yourself using the drawingManager tools.